# ROS topic structure?

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the basic structure of any topic on ROS?
My aim is to convert every topic to a binary data, that can be send on a network.
And again publish each topic from its respective binary data.

I am getting help from rosbag and wifi_comm packages. I am not getting complete information of basic structure of topic.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12359/ros-topic-structure?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2011-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look at [ROS' message serialization](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes).
It already does exactly what you want - convert it to binary and send it over a network.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not have to serialize the messages yourself when using wifi_com. You just create a new instance of the WifiComm class and tell it what topics to forward and it should just work. Try looking at the file examples/wifi_comm_example.cpp in the wifi_comm package. There doesn't seem to be much of a tutorial for it, sadly, but make sure to read it to find out about how to use olsrd also.

---

Originally posted by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) with karma: 317 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1